# OpenVPN server not starting up on boot

Tags: boot, openvpn

Good day,

I'm a first time newbie, so please bear with me.

I installed Openvpn on Ubuntu Server 16.04. After some configuration changes it all works; with one exception.

Openvpn service starts, but not the server. When I log in and try to start openvpn@server it doesn't work, but with the openvpn logs it's telling me that the IP is already in use. So I manually stopped the openvpn service and I started up again the openvpn@server, this works.

Basically I want the openvpn server to start on boot. All the articles I find relate to starting openvpn client on boot.

I also tried update-rc.d -f openvpn remove, how can I get the openvpn@server to be recognized as a service?

Any help is appreciated.

Darren

Comment: You'll need to look in the server log files a bit more to see why it's failing to start.  Assuming you installed with apt, it creates the systemd files to start the service.  So I would guess it's trying to start but failing on binding to an address.  If you can edit your question with more debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that was exactly the issue, a binding problem.

It's almost like a "vanilla" openvpn service was starting before by openvpn server and was taking the IP/port. So I went in and modified the /etc/default/openvpn file. Pointed the AUTOSTART to my server name and also added the full path to myserver.conf file in the OPTARGS

starts up fine now !

Thanks!